# Rails: How to retrieve the polymorphic '_type' column name for a polymorphic model dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism, metaprogramming

I basically want to create a concern which will be included in all the polymorphic models. This concern needs to have a dynamic setter method which which sets the value for the '_type' column.

```
module StiPolymorphable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    define_method "#{magic_method_to_get_type_column}=" do |type_field|
      super(type_field.to_s.classify.constantize.base_class.to_s)
    end
  end
end
```

I basically want to access all the addresses of a Parent instance instead of a Person instance.

Example -
Suppose I have the following classes

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Parent < Person end
class Teacher < Person end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  include StiPolymorphable

  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Right now if I try to access the addresses of a Parent it gives me zero records since the addressable_type field contains the value 'Person'.

```
 Parent.first.addresses => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 
 Person.first.addresses => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Address id: .....>]>
```

Comment: Can you give some more details of how you would use this module?

Comment: I'm basically trying to include this module in all the polymorphic models in my application which can belong_to an STI model.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I'm trying to make the polymorphic instance access the base class of the belonging STI model. If that makes any sense at all.
I'll edit the question to give a better example.

Comment: Can you create an example of what would be the outcome you want. Maybe adding the STI model example to OP.

Comment: @usmanali, I've added an example for clarity

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested on looking at [Modularity](https://github.com/makandra/modularity) gem so you could pass variables when you're including the Module. Haven't really tried it though. Hope it helps.

Comment: This really doesn't help me much right now. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

We do something like this:

```
module Shared::PolymorphicAnnotator
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    # @return [String]
    #    the polymorphic _id column
    def annotator_id
      reflections[annotator_reflection].foreign_key.to_s
    end

    # @return [String]
    #    the polymorphic _type column
    def annotator_type
      reflections[annotator_reflection].foreign_type
    end 
  end

  included do
    # Concern implementation macro
    def self.polymorphic_annotates(polymorphic_belongs, foreign_key = nil)
      belongs_to polymorphic_belongs.to_sym, polymorphic: true, foreign_key: (foreign_key.nil? ? (polymorphic_belongs.to_s + '_id').to_s : polymorphic_belongs.to_s)
      alias_attribute :annotated_object, polymorphic_belongs.to_sym 

      define_singleton_method(:annotator_reflection){polymorphic_belongs.to_s} 
    end

    attr_accessor :annotated_global_entity 

    # @return [String]
    #   the global_id of the annotated object
    def annotated_global_entity
      annotated_object.to_global_id if annotated_object.present?
    end

    # @return [True]
    #    set the object when passed a global_id String
    def annotated_global_entity=(entity)
      o = GlobalID::Locator.locate entity

      write_attribute(self.class.annotator_id, o.id)
      write_attribute(self.class.annotator_type, o.class.base_class)
      true
    end
  end
end
```

In your model:

```
class Foo
   include Shared::PolymorphicAnnotator
   polymorphic_annotates('belongs_to_name', 'foreign_key')
 end
```